# Is using additional arrays for sorting "legal"?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting

Is using additional arrays for sorting "legal"? I'm just curious because for me it is easier to divide the problem into smaller pieces using additional arrays and then to override the main array if the problem is bigger or more complex. Is that still sorting or not?

Tell me your opinions. I would be happy to hear it!

Comment: What does that even mean, *legal*? It's just a trade-off. You sacrifice space complexity for a reduction in code complexity (and possibly time complexity).

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen Well I was not sure myself I have homework and it says sorting algorithms so I'm using additional arrays for that, is that valid or not? They might be solvable using one array, but I would need to use too many if and loops.

Comment: Nobody can answer that question for you except the person that gave you the assignment. It all depends on what criteria are taken into account. If the focus is on space complexity, then creating additional arrays will be a losing strategy. If the focus is on time complexity, you might be able to create a more efficient algorithm using multiple arrays.